# Cloud Functions for Firebase for uploading image and resizing to new width

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I would like to leverage Cloud Functions for Firebase to resize an image on upload and overwrite the original so there is only one image per upload.

Also, rather than create an image with a specified width and height, I would like ImageMagick to resize based on a given width, such as 800px.

I've looked at the Firebase ImageMagick example for creating thumbnails on upload as a start but I don't see how to modify it meet this need. I would really appreciate an example for how to achieve this.

Edit: Here is the meat of the code I am using from Firebase's example (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js)

```
// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const tempFilePath = `/tmp/${fileName}`;
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
  destination: tempFilePath
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
  // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
  return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath]).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath);
    // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
    const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, '$1thumb_$2');
    // Uploading the thumbnail.
    return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
      destination: thumbFilePath
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom metadata instead of the "thumb_" prefix to avoid the function looping when you overwrite the original file path with the thumbnail:

```
const filePath = event.data.name
const metadata = event.data.metadata

if (metadata.isThumb) {
    console.log('Exiting: Already a thumbnail')
    return
}
```

You just need to set it after `spawn` finishes resizing:

```
    return spawn(/* ... */)
}).then(_ => {
    metadata.isThumb = true               // We add custom metadata
    const options = {
        destination: filePath,            // Destination is the same as original
        metadata: { metadata: metadata }
    }
    // Overwrite the original path
    return bucket.upload(/* localThumb */, options)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In imagemagick, you do it by

```
convert inputimage -resize 800x outputimage
```

without the height specified and only the width of 800 and "x", it will convert the width to 800 and make the height such that the aspect ratio is preseved.

Sorry, I do not know Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the bit of code I am working with to the original question. I see where I would replace the 200x200 with your suggestion of 800x. Additionally, it looks like I need to swap "-thumbnail" with "-resize". I'm still having trouble with overwriting the original image with the newly resized image.

Comment: specify a path to some other existing directory for your output image